# Magento 1 : Unable to save the Static blocks on edit existing blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

I have 1.9.0.3 Magento website, everything was fine, website wasnt edited in a year and when I tried to edit some existing static block and save or save and continue editing I am returned in CMS/Static Blocks panel and no changes are made.
It allows me to create new static block, but when I copy paste code from existing old block same happened.
What I noticed when playing with blocks when I copy/paste code from existing block in new block for example:

```
 <div id="banner-slider-demo-2-new" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-middle-narrow owl-banner-carousel">
    <div class="item" style="background:url({{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/02/13_new.jpg"}})
```

Cant save the new created block. When I remove word "style" everything is ok and block is saved. It happen with all lines with "style". Code is not proper without "style" but block is saved.
I flushed everything, deleted cache, same happened.
In system.log I found error that repeats 20 times per day in last 12 months:

2019-05-20T16:27:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /home/fedorsoaps/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/Socialfeeds/Helper/Data.php on line 79

And, line 79 in Data.php is:

```
 79    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
        $raw = $doc->saveXML($child);
        $li = preg_replace("/<li[^>]+\>/i", "", $raw);
        $peopleList[$i] = preg_replace("/<\/li>/i", "", $li);
        $i++;
```

Meanwhile website frontend is working normally but I cant make any changes.
I am not coder, just basic Magento installer, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without the smart tag (or whatever magento calls it).  So..

secure

`style="background:url('https://www.domain.name.com/media/wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/02/13_new.jpg')"`

or non-secure

`style="background:url('http://www.domain.name.com/media/wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/02/13_new.jpg')"`

Comment: Still cant "Save and Continue Edit", push me back in CMS/Static Blocks  menu when tried
.
This line Block wont save:
style="background:url("https://www.domain.name.com/media/wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/02/13_new.jpg"

This line block saved:
="background:url("https://www.domain.name.com/media/wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/02/13_new.jpg"

Also, with other lines with "style" mentioned.
Not saved Block:
 <p style="text-align:right;"><span style="color: #fff; vertical-align
Saved Block:
 <p         ="text-align:right;"><span style="color: #fff; vertical-align

Comment: I corrected my example. Also domain.name.com is your website address. You did that part?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Yes, I put my website name instead of domain.name.com and use corrected example, still same..
Not saved:
style="background:url('https://www.domain.name.com/media/wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/02/13_new.jpg')"
Saved Block:
="background:url('https://www.domain.name.com/media/wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/02/13_new.jpg')"

Comment: Ok, I didnt found solution for this, can someone tell me in what file/folder I can find static blocks in File Manager and can I edit them directly, without going trough Admin panel? Thanks